# Adding a node at the beginning of a Singly Linked List (C)

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

The code works without error but I cant seem to know why the new node is not being inserted to the beginning of the list. It probably has something to do with the `else` statement in the first function (`insertNode`) but I'm not sure, what's going on?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *link;
};

void insertNode(struct node *head, int x) {
    //Create node to be added and add the input integer to it
    struct node *temp;
    temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = x;

    //Check if there are any existing nodes in the list, if not, the let the head be equal to the new temp pointer
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = temp;
    } else {
        //If not, then we need to add the node to the beginning
        temp->link = head;
        head = temp;        
        printf("Node was added successfully!\n");
    }
}

int findsize(struct node *head) {
    //Finds the size of the list

    struct node *temp = head;
    int count = 0;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        count++;
        temp = temp->link;
    }
    return count;
}

void printData(struct node *head) {
    //Prints the elements of the list
    struct node *temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("Element: %d\n", temp->data);
        temp = temp->link;
    }
}

void main() {
    //Created a node and allocated memory
    struct node *head;
    head = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    //Added data to the node and created another one linked to it
    head->data = 15;
    head->link = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head->link->data = 30;
    head->link->link = NULL;
    //Used the above function to add a new node at the beginning of the list
    insertNode(head, 5);
    //Print the size of the list    
    printf("The size of the list you gave is: %d\n", findsize(head));
    //Print the elements of the list
    printData(head);
}
```

Comment: "adding a node" means changing some pointer, either the ->next pointer in another node or the (*external* or *global*) head pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you insert a node at the beginning of the list, you effectively change the beginning of the list, so this new initial node must be returned to the caller. The prototype for `insertNode()` must be changed to return the list head or to take a pointer to the list head.

Here is a modified version with the first approach:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *link;
};

struct node *insertNode(struct node *head, int x) {
    //Create node to be added and add the input integer to it
    struct node *temp;
    temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (temp != NULL) {
        temp->data = x;
        temp->link = head;
    }
    return temp;
}

int findsize(struct node *head) {
    //Find the size of the list
    struct node *temp = head;
    int count = 0;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        count++;
        temp = temp->link;
    }
    return count;
}

void printData(struct node *head) {
    //Prints the elements of the list
    struct node *temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("Element: %d\n", temp->data);
        temp = temp->link;
    }
}

void main() {
    //Created a node and allocated memory
    struct node *head = NULL;
    //Insert 3 nodes with values 30, 15 and 5
    head = insertNode(head, 30);
    head = insertNode(head, 15);
    head = insertNode(head, 5);
    //Print the size of the list    
    printf("The size of the list you gave is: %d\n", findsize(head));
    //Print the elements of the list
    printData(head);
    //Should free the nodes
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. However, I fail to see the difference in the end result between the two functions (yours and mine). I understand your function perfectly but isn't what you did similar to changing the value of head (writing head = temp (in my function vs. writing head = insertNode(head, 5); in yours). i.e. does the head revert to its original position after i exit the function?

Comment: @Ali: my function is simpler and most importantly **returns** the new value of `head` to the caller, where it is stored into its own list pointer with: `head = insertNode(head, 5);`. Your function did not return the new head to the caller, causing the list to stay unmodified in the `main` function since `head` still pointed to the previous list head.

Comment: You said "...since head still pointed to the previous list head". I realize I might be missing something major here (I'm still learning this), but doesn't (head=temp;) change the position of the head pointer so that It points to the new node, since temp is pointing to the new node?

Comment: @Ali: `head = temp` only updates the argument of the function `insertNode`, not the local variable with the same name in `main`. When you call `insertNode(head, 5);` in `main()`, a copy of the value of `head` is passed as the argument to the function, which by the way could be named differently in the definition of `insertNode`.